# git svn clone failed

Tags: git, git-svn

```
git svn clone url

Initialized empty Git repository in D:/code/Androi
d/ProjName/.git/
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem h
as no item: '/svn/Projects/!svn/rvr/100/Android/ProjName' path not found
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively
 for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
      4 [main] perl 8428 child_info_fork::abort: unable to map d:\Program Files\
Git\usr\bin\msys-svn_subr-1-0.dll, Win32 error 1114
open2: fork failed: Resource temporarily unavailable at /mingw64/share/perl5/sit
e_perl/Git.pm line 411.
```

after the command was executed, nothing was got from server.

If use the following commands, get the same result after the second command "git svn fetch"

```
$ git svn init url
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/code/Android/try1/.git/

johnliao@john-toshiba MINGW64 /d/code/Android/try1 (master)
$ git svn fetch
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: '/svn/Projects/!svn/rvr/100/Android/ProjName' path not found
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
      4 [main] perl 5472 child_info_fork::abort: unable to map D:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\msys-svn_subr-1-0.dll, Win32 error 1114
open2: fork failed: Resource temporarily unavailable at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git.pm line 411.
```

Comment: `unable to map d:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\msys-svn_subr-1-0.dll` That looks troublesome. Does that file exist? Does it exist on C:?

Comment: Not C:, D:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\msys-svn_subr-1-0.dll exists.

Comment: Have you tried `git svn init` with following `git svn fetch`?

Comment: Amaslenn, please have a look on the question part. I got the same error by your way.

Comment: @johnliao: Have you got any solution for this one? As we are facing some problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @amaslenn, after uninstalled the git and install the git 2.6.2 version, the problem was solved.

Comment: This problem is OK after installing Git-2.6.2-64-bit.exe

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug in the 64 bit version of git for windows >= 2.7.0, reported upstream:

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/708

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/650

The best option currently available is to use the 32 bit version, or previous 64 bit versions.

Comment: In my case, 2.6.2 works, but 2.7.0, 2.8.2, 2.8.3 not working.

Comment: FWIW, I still have problems with 2.9.3 64-bit, but 2.9.3 32-bit is fine.

Comment: Still a problem with version 2.12.1 64-bit. The 32-bit version works as expected.

Comment: Still a problem with version: git version 2.13.3.windows.1 (64-bit)

Comment: This is still an issue for me. I swapped 2.17 (64 bit) for 2.18 (32 bit) and it's now working again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solved by uninstalling git version 2.8.1 for windows 64 bit and installing the new git installer 2.8.2 for windows 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem on Git 2.10.0 and I solved it.
Working on windows server environment on AWS,instance type is T2.small.

At first,I installed the 64-bit version GIT for win and exec

```
git svn fetch
```

But Git said

```
C:\Program Files\
Git\usr\bin\msys-svn_subr-1-0.dll, Win32 error 1114
open2: fork failed: Resource temporarily unavailable at /mingw64/share/perl5/sit
e_perl/Git.pm line 411.
```

So,I installed the 32-bit version of GIT for win after uninstalling the 64-bit version.

When installing the 32-bit version,
need to select the option "Use MinTTY(the default terminal of MSYS2)" instead of "Use Windows' default console window".It's important to solve this problem.

If you select "Use Windows' default console window", "dash.exe" which is required to rebaseall doesn't install.

After the installation,just type followings.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin
dash -c "./dash rebaseall -v -p"
```

and typed like this again ,I got success.

```
git svn fetch
```

P.S

I tried to change the server instance type to T2.large.
There's no problem and I don't know why.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Same with version 2.10.0 - 64bit version fails, but 32bit version works.

Comment: Information could be added as a comment, people expect solutions as answer